# Boost.Spirit.x3 avoid collapsing two consecutive attributes of the same type into a vector

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am trying to learn Boost.Spirit, but I have found a difficulty.

I am trying to parse a string into the following structure:

```
struct employee {
    std::string name;
    std::string location;
};
```

And it seems that when two attributes with the same type are back to back, they collapse (logically) into a `std::vector` of that type. Because of that rule, the following parser

```
+x3::ascii::alnum >>
    +x3::space >>
    +x3::ascii::alnum
```

would have the attribute of `std::vector<std::string>`.

But I am trying to parse this into that `struct`, which means that the ideal attribute for me would be a `boost::fusion::tuple<std::string, std::string>`, so I can adapt my struct to it.

The complete version of the not working code (referenced above):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>


struct employee {
    std::string name;
    std::string location;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(employee, 
    (std::string, name),
    (std::string, location)
)

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

x3::rule<struct parse_emp_id, employee> const parse_emp = "Employee Parser";
auto parse_emp_def = 
    +x3::ascii::alnum >>
    +x3::space >>
    +x3::ascii::alnum
    ;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(parse_emp);

int main()
{
    std::string input = "Joe Fairbanks";
    
    employee ret;
    
    x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parse_emp, ret);
    
    std::cout << "Name: " << ret.name << "\tLocation: " << ret.location << std::endl;
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bacb11a9118f4c7b)

This code triggers a `static_assert` telling me that my attribute isn't correct:

```
error: static_assert failed "Attribute does not have the expected size."
```

With the command of

```
clang++ -std=c++14 test.cpp
```

(it also fails under GCC).

## What I have tried

I have found a workaround to this problem, but it is messy, and I can't believe that this is the cleanest way:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>


struct employee {
    std::string name;
    std::string location;
};

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

x3::rule<struct parse_emp_id, employee> const parse_emp = "Employee Parser";
auto parse_emp_def = 
    x3::eps [
    ([](auto& ctx) {
        x3::_val(ctx) = employee{};
    })
    ]>>
    (+x3::ascii::alnum)[
    ([](auto& ctx) {
        x3::_val(ctx).name = x3::_attr(ctx);
    })
    ]>>
    +x3::space >>
    (+x3::ascii::alnum)[
    ([](auto& ctx) {
        x3::_val(ctx).location = x3::_attr(ctx);
    })
    ]
    ;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(parse_emp);

int main()
{
    std::string input = "Joe Fairbanks";
    
    employee ret;
    
    x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parse_emp, ret);
    
    std::cout << "Name: " << ret.name << "\tLocation: " << ret.location << std::endl;
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bbb6e0e1c404260)

I really don't like that solution: it kinda ruins the amazing expressiveness of spirit and makes it super ugly, also if I want to add new fields into the `employee` struct, then I have to add an extra lambda, instead of just updating my `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`, which is much easier.

So the question is: Is there some way to (hopefully) cleanly split two consecutive attributes of the same type from the `std::vector` and into a `boost::fusion::vector`?

Thank you in advance for getting this far ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that unlike character literals, `x3::space` has an attribute. So you don't have an attribute of two separate character sequences separated by whitespace, but rather an attribute of one big character sequence which includes the whitespace.

[The `omit` directive](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/quick_reference/directive.html) is what you're after, and with that single addition your 'not working code' works. :-]

```
// Example program
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct employee {
    std::string name;
    std::string location;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(employee, name, location)

x3::rule<struct parse_emp_id, employee> const parse_emp = "Employee Parser";
auto parse_emp_def
    =      +x3::ascii::alnum
        >>  x3::omit[+x3::space]
        >> +x3::ascii::alnum
    ;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(parse_emp)

int main()
{
    std::string const input = "Joe Fairbanks";

    employee ret;
    x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parse_emp, ret);

    std::cout << "Name: " << ret.name << "\tLocation: " << ret.location << '\n';
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99bedeefdf00c4c8)</kbd>

Comment: It's a good day when the answer to a spirit question is already there before I find the question :) +1

Comment: @sehe : Hah! This is the first I've beat you to an X3 question surely, but then, this was a very easy one. ;-]

Comment: @Russel I'd suggest using a skipper instead of explicit whitespace (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965). [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/444dad3ed2859a35).

Comment: I would expect the omit directive to just remove the whitespace from the character sequence, not splitting it into two. Why does this work?

Comment: @RussellGreene : `omit` specifically _has no_ attribute, which is the key. `+x3::ascii::alnum >> +' ' >> +x3::ascii::alnum` would work as well with no need for `omit`, because character literals also do not have an attribute.